# Algorithm to find the best itinerary for traversing cities in a certain number of days

Tags: algorithm

I have a list of cities, and the distances between two neighbouring cities. Given a start and end city, I need to find the optimal route between them, given the constraint that it must be completed within a certain number of days.

What would be the algorithm that can achieve this?

EDIT: Example would be you start in city1 and end in city7. You have the distance between this and the previous city. You have 2 days to complete the journey, and you want the distances per day to be approximately equal. Also the route is defined, i.e. you're going through the cities in the order already defined, the only variation being which cities and how many you pass per day.

City1, 0
City2, 3
City3, 4
City4, 1
City5, 4
City6, 3
City7, 2

Comment: Can you place an example of input data?

Answer (score 2):

This is a constrained version of the Traveling Salesman Problem (TSP): https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem

Here is a paper that describes an algorithm for the time constrained version:

http://pubsonline.informs.org/doi/pdf/10.1287/opre.31.5.938

The authors use a branch and bound approach to solving the problem.

Comment: Seems like a slight variation given the time constraint. Seems like the edges have two types of cost -- a distance and a time, with one type of cost giving rise to the objective function and the other type of cost giving rise to a constraint.